# Ontotext Parameter defaut.min.distinct.threshold not honored

Tags: graphdb

Ontotext database throws 
`NotEnoughMemoryForDistinctGroupBy: Insufficient free Heap Memory ... , threshold:250Mb`
although parameter `defaut.min.distinct.threshold=1074000000`
set.

It seems that **setting the parameter is not taken into account** by the Ontotext engine und thus we are still getting the error.

We are using Ontotext 8.10.1-Free in Docker.
Running the container we provide as much memory to the container as is set for the Xmx parameter

We tried different memory settings Xms, Xmx and the aforementioned threshold parameter. But in the logs it states that the threshold's default value of 250m is being used.

This is how **our process info** looks at runtime:

```
>  ps auxw|grep java
root         1 85.4 47.1 5729308 964184 ?      Ssl  09:24   0:46 /docker-java-home/bin/java -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128G -Xms2g -Xmx2g -Ddefaut.min.distinct.threshold=1074000000  
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/graphdb/dist/heapdump.hprof -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dgraphdb.foreground=yes -Dgraphdb.dist=/opt/graphdb/dist -cp /opt/graphdb/dist/lib/* -Dgraphdb.home=/opt/graphdb/home com.ontotext.graphdb.server.GraphDBWorkbench
```

However, when we look into the **logs** (main-... .log) we see statements like these (mind the line where I added 2 stars at the beginning):

```
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:22,793 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.c.AbstractParameter] Configured parameter 'FSIPC' to default value '2'
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,138 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.g.s.StatementsController] POST SPARQL update request to repository
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,244 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.g.s.StatementsController] POST SPARQL update request to repository
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,299 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.f.s.RepositoryController] GET query -1149340244
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,334 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.c.AbstractParameter] Configured parameter 'order.construct' to default value 'false'
**[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,345 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.c.AbstractParameter] Configured parameter 'default.min.distinct.threshold' to default value '250.0M'
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,357 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.g.s.GraphQueryResultView] Request for query -1149340244 is finished
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,367 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.g.s.StatementsController] POST SPARQL update request to repository
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,415 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.g.s.StatementsController] POST SPARQL update request to repository
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,487 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.g.s.StatementsController] POST SPARQL update request to repository
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:33:23,704 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.f.s.RepositoryController] GET query 1759975767
```

Moreover the ontotext **logs** show the exceptions that can also be witnessed in the client running our tests and Sparql request against the DB:

```
[WARN ] 2019-08-08 09:41:10,442 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.t.u.DistinctMemoryMonitor] Insufficient free Heap Memory 238Mb for group by and distinct, threshold 250Mb,  reached 0Mb
[ERROR] 2019-08-08 09:41:10,469 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.t.SailConnectionImpl] Memory limit for GroupBy/Distinct reached
com.ontotext.trree.util.NotEnoughMemoryForDistinctGroupBy: Insufficient free Heap Memory 238Mb for group by and distinct, threshold:250Mb, reached 0Mb
        at com.ontotext.trree.util.DistinctMemoryMonitor.updateGroupByMemory(DistinctMemoryMonitor.java:73)
        at com.ontotext.trree.util.LongKeyBase.<init>(LongKeyBase.java:38)
        at com.ontotext.trree.util.LongKeySet.<init>(LongKeySet.java:26)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimDistinctIteration.<init>(OwlimDistinctIteration.java:20)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:639)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.java:65)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.iterator.JoinIterator.<init>(JoinIterator.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:824)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:237)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:796)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.java:65)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:650)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.java:65)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:135)
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluateWithRepoConnectionInternal(SailConnectionImpl.java:1786)
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluateWithRepoConnection(SailConnectionImpl.java:1679)
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluateInternal(SailConnectionImpl.java:249)
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluate(SailConnectionImpl.java:2316)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.helpers.SailUpdateExecutor.evaluateWhereClause(SailUpdateExecutor.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.helpers.SailUpdateExecutor.executeModify(SailUpdateExecutor.java:450)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.helpers.SailUpdateExecutor.executeUpdate(SailUpdateExecutor.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailUpdate.execute(SailUpdate.java:64)
        at com.ontotext.trree.monitorRepository.MonitorRepositoryConnection$1.execute(MonitorRepositoryConnection.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.statements.StatementsController.getSparqlUpdateResult(StatementsController.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.statements.StatementsController.handleRequestInternal(StatementsController.java:114)
        at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.StatementsController.handleRequestInternal(StatementsController.java:41)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.ontotext.forest.core.request.RequestFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.ontotext.forest.security.AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.java:38)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] 2019-08-08 09:41:10,549 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.f.s.GraphDBProtocolExceptionResolver] Error while handling request (500)
org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.ServerHTTPException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.UpdateExecutionException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: com.ontotext.trree.util.NotEnoughMemoryForDistinctGroupBy: Insufficient free Heap Memory 238Mb for group by and distinct, threshold:250Mb, reached 0Mb
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.statements.StatementsController.getSparqlUpdateResult(StatementsController.java:266)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.statements.StatementsController.handleRequestInternal(StatementsController.java:114)
        at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.StatementsController.handleRequestInternal(StatementsController.java:41)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.ontotext.forest.core.request.RequestFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.ontotext.forest.security.AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.java:38)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.UpdateExecutionException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: com.ontotext.trree.util.NotEnoughMemoryForDistinctGroupBy: Insufficient free Heap Memory 238Mb for group by and distinct, threshold:250Mb, reached 0Mb
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailUpdate.execute(SailUpdate.java:69)
        at com.ontotext.trree.monitorRepository.MonitorRepositoryConnection$1.execute(MonitorRepositoryConnection.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.statements.StatementsController.getSparqlUpdateResult(StatementsController.java:254)
        ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: com.ontotext.trree.util.NotEnoughMemoryForDistinctGroupBy: Insufficient free Heap Memory 238Mb for group by and distinct, threshold:250Mb, reached 0Mb
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluateWithRepoConnectionInternal(SailConnectionImpl.java:1815)
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluateWithRepoConnection(SailConnectionImpl.java:1679)
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluateInternal(SailConnectionImpl.java:249)
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluate(SailConnectionImpl.java:2316)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.helpers.SailUpdateExecutor.evaluateWhereClause(SailUpdateExecutor.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.helpers.SailUpdateExecutor.executeModify(SailUpdateExecutor.java:450)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.helpers.SailUpdateExecutor.executeUpdate(SailUpdateExecutor.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailUpdate.execute(SailUpdate.java:64)
        ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ontotext.trree.util.NotEnoughMemoryForDistinctGroupBy: Insufficient free Heap Memory 238Mb for group by and distinct, threshold:250Mb, reached 0Mb
        at com.ontotext.trree.util.DistinctMemoryMonitor.updateGroupByMemory(DistinctMemoryMonitor.java:73)
        at com.ontotext.trree.util.LongKeyBase.<init>(LongKeyBase.java:38)
        at com.ontotext.trree.util.LongKeySet.<init>(LongKeySet.java:26)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimDistinctIteration.<init>(OwlimDistinctIteration.java:20)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:639)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.java:65)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.iterator.JoinIterator.<init>(JoinIterator.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:824)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:237)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:796)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.java:65)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:650)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.StrictEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(StrictEvaluationStrategy.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.evaluate(TupleFunctionEvaluationStrategy.java:65)
        at com.ontotext.trree.query.OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.evaluate(OwlimEvaluationStrategyImpl.java:135)
        at com.ontotext.trree.SailConnectionImpl.evaluateWithRepoConnectionInternal(SailConnectionImpl.java:1786)
        ... 54 common frames omitted
[INFO ] 2019-08-08 09:41:10,666 [repositories/kg-test-graph-import | c.o.g.s.StatementsController] POST SPARQL update request to repository
```

**What are our options to mitigate the situation?**
Currently I am not able to proceed with our software to get it up and running again due to the failing tests.
Backround here is that we are evaluating to switch to Ontotext from another triple store.

Lots of thanks and

best regards
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Got it working for now.

It seems to be a Docker Mac specific problem. By default, only 2GB of memory gets allocated to the docker engine. Raising that and giving the onto process enough memory (Xmx) solved the problem for me now.

See below screenshot for the settings.

Got there by DockerIcon -> Preferences -> Advanced

[Docker memory preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDshl.png)

Comment: Think there is a typo in the name of the parameter - it should be `-Ddefault.min.distinct.threshold` instead of `-Ddefaut.min.distinct.threshold`  - note the missing `l` in `default`. That has been fixed/changed in GDB-8.8 release and you are using 8.10.1